# Find $a, b, c$ minimizing MSE

Tags: regression, linear-regression, mse

Suppose you are given a "dummy" classifier. It looks like this:
$$
y(x) = \begin{cases} a \text{ if } x >= c \\ b \text{ else } \end{cases}
$$

Given some data set $\{(y_1, x_1), \dots (y_n, x_n)\}$ how to estimate $a, b, c$ such that the MSE would be minimal?

Comment: This is possible, but right now it doesn't make sense, because there are no constraints on a and b, so they could be a=b, since that is where the global minimum is. Alternatively you can just set c to some arbitrary value which will never be true, so that it will never have any effect, and the regular mean will be optimized.

Comment: @user2974951, thanks! I thought about the simplest case, but your answer clarified this even more.